# Spring RestController response mixed with PrometheusMeterRegistry error message

Tags: servlet-filters, spring-boot-actuator, spring-micrometer

Env: Springboot-2.0.7.RELEASE (embedded tomcat-8.5.35), JDK-1.8.0_181, micrometer-registry-prometheus-1.0.8

Desc: using `@Timed` on controller method and `WebMvcMetricsFilter` with custom `WebMvcTagsProvider`.

Demo project: https://github.com/kenix/resp-mix

If `PrometheusMeterRegistry` already created a meter with a set of tags, it won't create another meter with same name and a set of different tags. It throws `IllegalArgumentException` with the aforementioned reason. This happens after the normal processing of request, which is successful (response now has the converted JSON). The exception isn't caught in spring's `WebMvcMetricsFilter` (i.e. catch the exception in its `catch`-clause. BTW, `ControllerAdvice` doesn't help), but is caught by tomcat's `StandardHostValve`, which renders his own error message (it cannot know where this exception is from) into response too. This leads to an illegal JSON as the rendered result.

Question 1: should `WebMvcMetricsFilter` catch and handle this Exception thrown by `PrometheusMeterRegistry` and not throw it further up?

Question 2: have seen that exception in filter chain before hitting the actual processing is handled as expected. What about exception after a successful actual processing? Any references?

To trigger this case:

1. `curl -i localhost:8080/hi/foo/there`
2. `curl -i localhost:8080/hi/blah/there`

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: No, WebMvcTagsProvider handles HTTP Exceptions.
Question 2: Try using ControllerAdvice and catch the IllegalArgumentException there.

Comment: `WebMvcTagsProvider ` can handle HTTP exception, only when an exception is given to him. In this case no such exception occurred yet at that point. `ControllerAdvice` added now, but doesn't solve the problem. Didn't research much, guess `ControllerAdvice` only handles exceptions during processing phase, not after.